# How do i reduce time complexity when using two nested while loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, while-loop

first input will be number of test cases `t`, then given two numbers `a` and `b` you have to perform `i` operations such that,

- add 1 to `a` if `i` is odd
- add 2 to `a` if `i` is even

now print YES if `a` can become equal to `b` and NO if it can't

when I tried to submit my solution `i` got error that time limit is exceeded.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, a, b;
    cin >> t;
    while (t)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        int flag = 1;
        while (a != b && a < b)
        {
            if (flag % 2 == 0)
            {
                a += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                a += 1;
            }
            flag++;
        }
        if (a == b)
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)!

Comment: If `a < b` then they *cannot* be equal either, so the first check for inequality is redundant and should be omitted. You could skip the `if` and the modulo operation if you start with `flag = 0` and do within the loop `a += 1 + flag; flag = 1 - flag;` which will always turn `flag` into `0` and `1` one after another. Still you don't need all this as there's a direct formula available, see given answer.

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually iterate from `a` to `b`, just use the following observations to solve:

- After 2 operations, the value of `a` increases by `3`. So after an even number of operations (let number be `2k`), `a` increases by `3k`.
- Similarly, for an odd number of operations (of form `2k+1`), `a` increases by `3k+1`.

As you can see, `a` can either be increased by `3k` or `3k+1`, which implies that `b` will be reachable from `a` if `(b-a) mod 3 = (0 or 1)` (and obviously, if `b>a`). You can check this in `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: Provided `b >= a` at all...

Comment: @Aconcagua pretty trivial, but added to the answer

Comment: Sure – but you cannot imagine how often people overlook those trivialities ;)

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop can be simplified into a math expression. We can come up with the model using some examples.

For example, if a = 10, b = 20.

```
Loop 1 a += 1 (11)
Loop 2 a += 2 (13)
Loop 3 a += 1 (14)
Loop 4 a += 2 (16)
...
```

We can see that after two operations, a increases by 3. Which can be generalized, that after the 2n operation (which represents an even number), that a increases by 3n. On the other hand after the 2n + 1 operation (odd numbers), a is equal to an increase of 3n + 1. Thus, a can be increased either by 3n or 3n+1. Thus, 3n or 3n+1 has to be able to be equal to the difference of  a and b, which in this case is 10.

Thus either

```
1. 3 has to divide b - a, (b-a)%3 = 0 
2. 3 has to divide b - a with a remainder of 1, (b-a)%3=1
```

Thus, instead of a loop, using a mathematical expression can simply the runtime to O(1) per input.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Sorry. I was writing the solution as you posted.